# flask-mail is working only in main script

Tags: python, flask, flask-mail

I have a Flask server and I'm using Flask-mail. After installing it via pip, I configured the file `flask_server.py` in this way:

```
from flask_mail import Mail, Message 

app = flask.Flask(__name__, static_folder='static')

app.config['MAIL_SERVER']='smtp.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'myemail@gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'mypw'
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = False
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
mail= Mail(app)
```

Always in `flask_server.py` I have this function that sends mail:

```
def send_email():
   msg = Message('Title', sender = 'myemail@gmail.com', recipients = ['target@gmail.com'])
   msg.body = "Hello"
   mail.send(msg)
```

If I try to send mail in one the API, it works. For example:

```
@app.route('/computeModels', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def compute_models():
    send_email()
```

Now I want to remove the call `send_email()` and put it in the function of another script.

In `models.py` I worked in this way:

```
import flask_server as fs

def try_mail():
    fs.send_email()
```

The function is executed like in the first case but email does not arrive.

Comment: I'm no expert but I believe it should be `from flask_server import send_email` then you just do `send_email()`

Comment: I tried but this is not the problem.